# Create embedded charts with custom label

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I want to create a line chart using the EmbeddedChart from the Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service. I have a set of (x,y) coordinates in column A and B of a spreadsheet, and I want to draw the corresponding line in a chart with Apps Script.

```js
function newChart() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Page 2");
   var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
   chartBuilder.addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:B30"))
       .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE);
   sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
 }
```

The problem with this function is that it creates a chart with two lines instead of one. In order to have the correct chart, I have to manually edit the advanced settings, and check the option "Use column A as labels".

Is there an option to specify this setting using Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data table for a Chart is interpreted automatically to determine what roles each column performs.<sup>[ref](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles)</sup> If your first column contains text, its role will be "domain", and *"Domain columns specify labels along the major axis of the chart."*

You haven't shared your data in your question, but it's a safe bet that column A contains numbers or dates. Here's what your code produces when column A contains text:

[image: screenshot]

So the question is, can the role for a column be specified in an Embedded Chart? Unfortunately, no it can't.

As a work-around, you could replicate the numeric or date values in column A into another column as text.

Comment: Your work-around is really helpful, thanks. The documentation doesn't mention how to set a cell as plain text but it is possible to use [setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) just like this : `sheet.getRange("A1:A30").setNumberFormat("@");`

Comment: That will work in some cases, but not all. (Calculated dates, for example.) That's why I mentioned replicating the column, expecting that an appropriate text formatting function would be used; could be a spreadsheet function or script. (Or use [sheetConverter](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter).)